# Installing a Python program on Linux

Tags: python, linux

I wrote a Python program. I would like to add to it an installation script that will set up everything necessary - like desktop icon, entry in the menu, home directory file, etc.

I'm working on Linux (ubuntu). When a Python program is installed, what needs to happen in general? I know that it probably depends on the nature of the program.

Can you give me some general ideas? Or, point me in the right direction? I have no idea how to look for this on Google.

Thanks

Comment: [Snapcraft](https://snapcraft.io/) looks like a good option. There's a nice tutorial: [Snap a python application](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/snap-a-python-application#0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's a Python program you're trying to package, you should consider using its 'standard' distribution framework [distutils](http://docs.python.org/library/distutils.html). I can't replicate the entire document here but I'd recommend that you read it. Once you're done with that, check out the [Hitchhikers guide to packaging](https://the-hitchhikers-guide-to-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) which contains details on distribute - the extensions to distutils that allow you to package and distribute more effectively.

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu if you want it to be easily distributable to other Ubuntu users it'll have to be packaged properly, which is no simple task.  You might want to consult their [Packaging Guide](http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/) for more information.

Otherwise, generally speaking there are a few standard packaging options for Python.  Setuptools is popular, but becoming reviled lately.  Read [James Bennett's blog post "On Packaging"](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2008/dec/14/packaging/) for a decent in-depth look into the ups and downs of the Python packaging world.

Comment: Packaging is actually fairly simple, I recommend it. When the `.deb` package is done, use `alien` to convert it to `.rpm`. This gets you on most sane/worthwhile distributions.

Comment: Pasi: Do you know of a simple guide for making .deb packages? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could create an rpm easily using checkinstall. Search for checkinstall in google and download it. It will allow you to create an rpm and set the options.

Answer (score 0):

How a program is launched and placed in the menu is determined by a .desktop file (you can read the [specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/) or just look at some examples from `/usr/share/applications`). Properly installing a program (placing all files in the right directories and so on) requires either making a package like a deb or rpm, or you could use something like distutils or setuptools.

It may also help to just look at some (open source) examples of Python programs for Linux.